# Scala/Akka Socket Server IterateeRef syntax

Tags: scala, akka

Can somebody please explain to me the meaning of this line of code?

```
val state = IO.IterateeRef.Map.async[IO.Handle]()(context.dispatcher)
```

(from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/io.html)

I guess this is a partial application of the async function, which is a curried function?  But I thought that async was defined in IO.IterateeRef, not IO.IterateeRef.Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Object** IterateRef (akka API) [http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/#akka.actor.IO$$IterateeRef$](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/#akka.actor.IO%24%24IterateeRef%24)